# How do I add columns to a table created using serde when creating a Hive table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

- table desc info

```
hive> desc log23;
OK
col_name        data_type       comment
17/05/25 10:49:12 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
host                    string                  from deserializer
remote_host             string                  from deserializer
remote_logname          string                  from deserializer
remote_user             string                  from deserializer
request_time            string                  from deserializer
request_method          string                  from deserializer
request_url             string                  from deserializer
first_line              string                  from deserializer
http_status             string                  from deserializer
bytes                   string                  from deserializer
referer                 string                  from deserializer
agent                   string                  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.049 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
```

- apache log format serialize

```
serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe, parameters:{output.format.string=%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s, serialization.format=1, input.regex=([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\[[^\]]*\]) "(.[A-Z]*) (.*) (.*)" (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*) "(.*)" "(.*)"})
```

- Add a column using Alter query

```
hive> alter table log23 add columns (code string);

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
Error: type expected at the position 0 of derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:<derived from deserializer:derived from deserializer:string but>'<' is found.`
```

I get an error like above failed. How do I add a column...?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you cannot add columns if you've used serde. It is a known issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17713

Answer (score 0):

ADD COLUMNS lets you add new columns to the end of the existing columns but before the partition columns. This is supported for Avro backed tables as well, for [Hive 0.14](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7446) and later.

REPLACE COLUMNS removes all existing columns and adds the new set of columns. This can be done only for tables with a native SerDe (DynamicSerDe, MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe, LazySimpleSerDe and ColumnarSerDe). Refer to [Hive SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide#DeveloperGuide-HiveSerDe) for more information. REPLACE COLUMNS can also be used to drop columns. For example, "ALTER TABLE test_change REPLACE COLUMNS (a int, b int);" will remove column 'c' from test_change's schema.

Comment: I tried to replace it with the above answer, but I get the following error.


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Replace columns is not supported for table default.log23. SerDe may be incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the same but i am able to create a table and added the columns at the end:

create table log23 (host String, remote_host String);
alter table log23 add columns(code String);

which is working with textfile format. please let me know if you are using different file format so that i try to replicate the use.

Comment: I applied apache log format in serde format when creating table. I can add columns when creating regular tables rather than serde type. Please understand and answer your questions :(